# Svelte losing state between routes (svelte-spa-router)

Tags: javascript, svelte-3

An input component receives as prop a list of values to autocomplete. When route is changed `autocomplete` function doesn't run anymore (autocomplete is not available), loses state or it doesn't get reinitialized.

```
export let autoCompleteList = undefined

if (autoCompleteList) {
    onMount(() => {
        let input = document.getElementById(id)
        autocomplete({some_parameters})
    })

    onDestroy(() => {
        autoCompleteList = undefined
    })
}
```

Tried to add `onDestroy` to reset `autoCompleteList`, but has no effect. Adding a `key` may re-init the component but I don't know where to add it.

Comment: What is the autocomplete function?

Comment: It's kraaden's [autocomplete package](https://github.com/kraaden/autocomplete) here is the [link to component](https://github.com/ClimenteA/cdi/blob/master/src/Widgets/Box/Box.svelte). That component it's used [here](https://github.com/ClimenteA/cdi/blob/master/src/FindRoom/FindRoom.svelte#L166) and [here](https://github.com/ClimenteA/cdi/blob/master/src/AddRoom/AddRoom.svelte#L169). Swiching between them makes autocomplete lose state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input component had the same `id` name (even if input component was a child in different components). Changing `id` solved the issue.